# tileserver-gl + maplibre setup, map gets shown with no labels

Tags: labeling, tileserver-gl

I'm getting my data from `geofabrik.de`, render them using `tilemaker`, then I serve them using `tileserver-gl` and it by default uses `maplibre`. My styles are the default/example styles that tileserver uses in its example [here](https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl), which are `osm-bright` and `klokantech-basic`.

I did this procedure for data of **Iran (Perso-Arabic script)**, **Iraq (Arabic script)**, and **U.S. (English/Latin script)**. NO LABELS on map of Iran and Iraq, but HAS LABELS on map of the U.S.